# Change Labels of Time Axis using ggplot in R

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, time, time-series

I'm sure this is a relatively simple fix, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I'm trying to plot a scatter plot for date and time information. Here is some sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)

time <- c("19:36:00", "18:20:00", "17:59:00", "17:22:00", "17:23:00")
date <- c("10-05-2019", "25-01-2019", "13-04-2019", "22-07-2019", "05-12-2019")

data <- data.frame(time = as_hms(as_datetime(time, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Los_Angeles")), date = parse_date_time(date, "dmy", tz = "America/Los_Angeles"))

data %>% 
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = time)) +
  scale_y_datetime(
    breaks = scales::date_breaks("1 hour"),
    date_labels = "%l %p"
  )
```

The result of this plot is a y-axis that corresponds to time in AM/PM format. The default here is about 4:30 PM to 8:30 PM.  But, what if I wanted to change the limits of the y-axis to 4 PM to 10 PM? I've been combing through forums but I can't find anything that explicitly details this situation and the documentation only provides examples for doing this with date information.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `limits` in `scale_y_datetime` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%T"), 
         date = as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = time)) +
  scale_y_datetime(
     breaks = scales::date_breaks("1 hour"),
     date_labels = "%l %p",
     limits = c(as.POSIXct("16:00:00", format = "%T"),
                as.POSIXct("22:00:00", format = "%T")))
```

[image]

**data**

```
time <- c("19:36:00", "18:20:00", "17:59:00", "17:22:00", "17:23:00")
date <- c("10-05-2019", "25-01-2019", "13-04-2019", "22-07-2019", "05-12-2019")
data <- data.frame(time, date)
```